# How to Insert Or update Database row in this case

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a table as

```
CREATE TABLE `category` (
  `category_id` int(11) ,
  `T1` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `T2` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `T3` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `T4` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `T5` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL
 )

mysql> select * from category;
+-------------+----------+-------------+---------------+------+------+
| category_id | T1       | T2          | T3            | T4   | T5   |
+-------------+----------+-------------+---------------+------+------+
|         145 | Pop Corn | Regular Tub | Plain Salted  | NULL | NULL |
|         150 | Pop Corn | Buckets     | Plain Salted  | NULL | NULL | 
|         151 | Pop Corn | Jumbo       | Plain Salted  | NULL | NULL | 
|         152 | Pop Corn | Regular Tub | Butter Scotch | NULL | NULL | 
|         153 | Pop Corn | Regular Tub | Tomoto Tango  | NULL | NULL | 
|         154 | Pop Corn | Buckets     | Butter Scotch | NULL | NULL | 
|         222 | Pop Corn | NULL        | NULL          | NULL | NULL |
| +-------------+----------+-------------+---------------+------+-----
```

When i run the below program it is inserting a new Record in the table as shown below

```
223     Pop Corn | Buckets     | NULL          | NULL | NULL
```

It should actually Update the row of category_id 222 as Pop Corn is already existing

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
public class TestDate {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String  inputrequest = "Pop Corn@Buckets";
        String values[] = inputrequest.split("@");  
        String sqlselect = "";

        Connection dbConnection = null;
        PreparedStatement selectpst = null;
        ResultSet resultset = null;
        PreparedStatement selectpst2 = null;
        ResultSet resultset2 = null;
        String  sqlselect2 = "";

        Statement updateStatement  = null;

        // Length == 2
        if(values.length==2)
        {
            sqlselect = "select category_id  from category where T1 = ? AND T2 = ? AND T3 IS NULL"  
            selectpst = dbConnection.prepareStatement(sqlselect);
            selectpst.setString(1, values[0]);
            selectpst.setString(2, values[0]);
            resultset = selectpst.executeQuery();
            if(resultset.next())
            {
                System.out.println("Already exists");
            }
            else
            {
                sql = "Insert into category (T1,T2,T3,T4,T5) values ('"+values[0]+"','"+values[1]+"',NULL,NULL,NULL) ";
                updateStatement.executeUpdate(sql);
            }

        }
}
}
```

Could anybody please help me how to resolve this ??

Comment: your select can't return row with category_id 222 as T2 is NULL and doesn't equal "Buckets". Besides if you want to update a row you should use... an "UPDATE" and not an INSERT

Comment: Probably a little bug: `selectpst.setString(2, values[0]);`; I think it should be `selectpst.setString(2, values[1]);`

Answer (score 1):

You set your parameters wrong:

```
selectpst.setString(1, values[0]);
selectpst.setString(2, values[0]);
```

I think it should be:

```
selectpst.setString(1, values[0]);
selectpst.setString(2, values[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the correct data in the statement, so replace:

```
selectpst.setString(1, values[0]);
selectpst.setString(2, values[0]);
```

with

```
selectpst.setString(1, values[0]);
selectpst.setString(2, values[1]);
```

Then change your query. It's not correct. The row with id `222` has NULL on T2 and T3.

You are sending the value `Buckets` to T2 instead of `NULL` so it will never return the desired row.

Comment: Thanks for the comment so what should be the query ??

Comment: @PreethiJain Do you have a general rule for finding the row or just that specific one?

Comment: There is no general rule , means i have to implement this logic till T5 .

Comment: @PreethiJain sqlselect = "select category_id  from category where T1 = ? AND T2 IS NULL AND T3 IS NULL"  (so it has only the first param) you then remove selectpst.setString(2, values[1]); If you need the T1 and T2 in your code then you must ensure that the database doesn't contain null on those 2 fields.

Comment: @PreethiJain your initial code will work if you correct the data in the table, i'm pretty sure T2 should not be null!

Comment: so are there no constraints here? everything except ID can be null?

Comment: Only Id and T1 can't be null .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66485/discussion-between-preethi-jain-and-mihaic).

Comment: @PreethiJain Then you need to get all the rows for T1=value, then compare each column value with your other values for each row.

Comment: Yes you are correct , but initially i am facing a problem which is it is inserting twice in the database for the same values .